# go-socket.io invalid transport

Tags: go, socket.io

I'm trying to use the go-socket.io library to build an online chat with golang
so I made a simple structure, following the examples in the documentation

my main.go looks like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

    socketio "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"
)

func GinMiddleware(allowOrigin string) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowOrigin)
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT, DELETE")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Content-Length, X-CSRF-Token, Token, session, Origin, Host, Connection, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, X-Requested-With")

        if c.Request.Method == http.MethodOptions {
            c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusNoContent)
            return
        }

        c.Request.Header.Del("Origin")

        c.Next()
    }
}

func main() {
    router := gin.New()

    server := socketio.NewServer(nil)

    server.OnConnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn) error {
        s.SetContext("")
        log.Println("connected:", s.ID())
        return nil
    })

    server.OnEvent("/", "notice", func(s socketio.Conn, msg string) {
        log.Println("notice:", msg)
        s.Emit("reply", "have "+msg)
    })

    server.OnEvent("/chat", "msg", func(s socketio.Conn, msg string) string {
        s.SetContext(msg)
        return "recv " + msg
    })

    server.OnEvent("/", "bye", func(s socketio.Conn) string {
        last := s.Context().(string)
        s.Emit("bye", last)
        s.Close()
        return last
    })

    server.OnError("/", func(s socketio.Conn, e error) {
        log.Println("meet error:", e)
    })

    server.OnDisconnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn, msg string) {
        log.Println("closed", msg)
    })

    go func() {
        if err := server.Serve(); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("socketio listen error: %s\n", err)
        }
    }()
    defer server.Close()

    router.Use(GinMiddleware("http://localhost:3000"))
    router.GET("/socket.io/*any", gin.WrapH(server))
    router.POST("/socket.io/*any", gin.WrapH(server))
    router.StaticFS("/public", http.Dir("../asset/index.html"))

    if err := router.Run(":8000"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed run app: ", err)
    }
}
```

my front end looks like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      var s2 = io("/chat");

      socket.on('reply', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });

      $('form').submit(function(){
        s2.emit('msg', $('#m').val(), function(data){
          $('#messages').append($('<li>').text('ACK CALLBACK: ' + data));
        });

        socket.emit('notice', $('#m').val());

        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but when running the code in the browser, by the url: http://localhost:8000/socket.io/
i get this error:

```
invalid transport: %!s(<nil>)
```

why?
I tried to use some tips from this site:

```
https://socket.io/docs/v3/troubleshooting-connection-issues/
```

but no alternative helped me

Comment: The URL you need to run in the browser is `http://localhost:8000`. That represents your static web server. `http://localhost:8000/socket.io/` represents your websocket endpoint, which `socket.io-1.4.5.js`  must call. It needs to do a proper handshake and set the correct headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the issue pointed out by @code_monk, the following code is incorrect too:

```golang
router.StaticFS("/public", http.Dir("../asset/index.html"))
```

As the name implies, `http.Dir` is a directory instead of a file, so the correct code should be:

```golang
router.StaticFS("/public", http.Dir("../asset"))
```

And the URL to open in the browser is: http://localhost:8080/public/.

---

If you want to serve a single file, you can use `StaticFile` instead:

```golang
router.StaticFile("/", "../asset/index.html")
```

And the URL to open in the browser is: http://localhost:8080/.

---

Pay attention to `../asset` too. Maybe you mean `./asset` (depends on the directory structure of your files).